# How I can mock the request with a session having array driver so I can test my guard?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, testing, laravel-10

I am testing my Custom guard:

```php
namespace Tests\Feature\Extensions;

use App\Models\Customer;
use App\Extensions\CustomerUser;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Mockery;
use Tests\TestCase;

class CustomGuardTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    public function testAuthSuccess(): void
    {
        // Password is by default 1234
        $customer = CustomerUser::factory()->create();

        $request = $this->app->make('request');

        $guard = new CustomGuard('customer_session', Auth::createUserProvider('customer'), $request);
        $authenticated = $guard->attempt(['email' => $customer->email, 'password' => '1234', 'user_id' => $customer->user_id]);

        $this->assertTrue($authenticated);
    }
}
```

But upon test I get the error:

```
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Feature\Extensions\CustomerGuardTest::testAuthSuccess
RuntimeException: Session store not set on request.

/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php:560
/var/www/html/app/Extensions/CustomerGuard.php:13
/var/www/html/tests/Feature/Extensions/CustomerGuardTest.php:25
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:61
```

And I try to test that my guard will authenticate with my email,password and user_id whislt if Not provided user won't be authenticated.

The guard is as follows:

```
namespace App\Extensions;

use Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CustomGuard extends SessionGuard
{
    public function __construct($name, UserProvider $provider, Request $request)
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $provider, $request->session() ,$request);
    }

    public function attempt(array $credentials = [], $remember = false)
    {
        $user = $this->provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);
        // Check if the retrieved user exists and the password is correct
        if ($user && $this->provider->validateCredentials($user, $credentials)) {
            // Log in the user
            $this->login($user, $remember);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Whereas my provider is:

```
namespace App\Extensions;

use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as UserContract;
class CustomeProvider extends EloquentUserProvider
{
    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        if (empty($credentials) ||
            (count($credentials) === 1 && array_key_exists('password', $credentials))) {
            return null;
        }
        // Retrieve the customer based on the email and user_id
        return $this->createModel()->newQuery()
            ->where('email', $credentials['email'])
            ->where('user_id', $credentials['user_id'])
            ->first();
    }

    public function validateCredentials(UserContract $customer, array $credentials)
    {
        if(isset($credentials['user_id']) && (int)$customer->user_id==$credentials['user_id']){
            return parent::validateCredentials($customer,$credentials);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Do you know How I can fix the error? I want to ensure that my guard works so I can be sure that I can apply them upon my routes.

Comment: Personally, I would check this with a feature test; e.g. post data to the login controller and ensure you're authenticated afterwards. Mocking requests is not easy, and is explicitly recommended against [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mocking#mocking-facades).

Comment: So I need to make a middleware or route for it and test through routing?

Comment: Feature testing means using the features of the program in the same way an end user would. So just post a login like. `$this->post(route('login'), ['email' => $customer->email, 'password' => '1234', 'user_id' => $customer->user_id])` or similar, and check for expected status code, redirect to home page, welcome message on page, etc.

Comment: So I need to make routes and Controllers as well.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would have an authentication guard but not routes and controllers?

Comment: Imwill have but first I want to test them seperately.

Comment: I strongly suggest to do what @miken32, else you need to do a unit test and that is more complex.